# SplitButton in toolbar not triggering click handler when moved to overflow button while resizing screen

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Recently we observed that when split button is moved under overflow button while screen is resized click handler for split button is not getting triggered.
It works fine when its not in overflow button.

I came across this [Github issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/4542) which seems to be still open.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
    items: [{
      type: "button",
      text: "Button"
    }, {
      type: "button",
      text: "Toggle Button",
      togglable: true
    }, {
      type: "splitButton",
      text: "Insert",
      click: splitButtonClickHandler,
      menuButtons: [{
        text: "Insert above",
        icon: "insert-up"
      }, {
        text: "Insert between",
        icon: "insert-middle"
      }, {
        text: "Insert below",
        icon: "insert-down"
      }]
    }, {
      type: "separator"
    }, {
      template: "<label for='dropdown'>Format:</label>"
    }, {
      template: "<input id='dropdown' style='width: 150px;' />",
      overflow: "never"
    }, {
      type: "separator"
    }, {
      type: "buttonGroup",
      buttons: [{
        icon: "align-left",
        text: "Left",
        togglable: true,
        group: "text-align"
      }, {
        icon: "align-center",
        text: "Center",
        togglable: true,
        group: "text-align"
      }, {
        icon: "align-right",
        text: "Right",
        togglable: true,
        group: "text-align"
      }]
    }, {
      type: "buttonGroup",
      buttons: [{
        icon: "bold",
        text: "Bold",
        togglable: true
      }, {
        icon: "italic",
        text: "Italic",
        togglable: true
      }, {
        icon: "underline",
        text: "Underline",
        togglable: true
      }]
    }, {
      type: "button",
      text: "Action",
      overflow: "always"
    }, {
      type: "button",
      text: "Another Action",
      overflow: "always"
    }, {
      type: "button",
      text: "Something else here",
      overflow: "always"
    }]
  });

  $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: "Paragraph",
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: [{
        text: "Heading 1",
        value: 1
      },      {
        text: "Heading 2",
        value: 2
      },      {
        text: "Heading 3",
        value: 3
      },      {
        text: "Title",
        value: 4
      },      {
        text: "Subtitle",
        value: 5
      }    ]
  });
});

function splitButtonClickHandler(e) {
  alert('triggered')
  console.log(e, 'triggered')
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/toolbar/index">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.406/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.406/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.406/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
    <div id="toolbar"></div>
  </div>
```

Dojo reproducing the issue: https://dojo.telerik.com/aKAseZAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment in that very issue:

> It works fine if the splitButton items have their own click handlers
>   defined.
>
> I think a more accurate description would be:
>
> - when not overflown, the children without their own handler properly    inherit the click handler from the parent
> - when overflown, such children don't inherit the handler.

Which gives us a direct workaround: re-declare the handler for each child:

```
{
    type: "splitButton",
    text: "Insert",
    click: splitButtonClickHandler,
    menuButtons: [
        { text: "Insert above", icon: "insert-up", click: splitButtonClickHandler },
        { text: "Insert between", icon: "insert-middle", click: splitButtonClickHandler },
        { text: "Insert below", icon: "insert-down", click: splitButtonClickHandler }
    ]
}
```

Feel also free to upvote or comment the issue on GitHub so Telerik prioritizes it higher.

Comment: Let  me give a try

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot @GaloisGirl. I have raised a support ticket to Kendo for this issue.